# Copy excel file to sql table in ADF. And choose range of each columns dynamically and map the columns dynamically

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have to copy an excel file into a sql table. And I only want some columns with specific range to get copied.And range must be choosen dynamically.

For this I have created a table with two columns: Column Names and Range.
And used Lookup activity to use them in Adf. And then used ForEach activity and inside ForEach activity I have used copy activity but I am not getting proper output.
Please can anyone tell me the flow of pipeline which I can use.

Comment: what do u mean by "range must be choosen dynamically" ? Can you please share an example of your data ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not supported to specify dynamic range for multiple columns for excel format in the **dataset Range** option.

But, you can try the below approach for it which involves little **manual work** at the end of SQL.

Please follow below steps:

- First create the dataset for excel and give any string parameter as Range for it.
  [image]
- This is the excel data that I am using.

[image]

- Now, create an array variable for the range of columns and give your range like this

`["A1:A5","C1:C5"]`

[image]

- Join this with the ForEach activity and give this variable in the settings of it.

[image]

- Inside the ForEach, drag a **copy activity** and give the source excel dataset and give the ForEach `@item()` in the dataset parameters.
  [image]
- Go to sink and create the dataset for SQL with the file name like below.

  `@concat(utcNow(),'table')`

  [image]
- In the sink check on Auto create table.
  [image]
- Execute this pipeline and you will get the tables in SQL database. If you select the same table for every iteration, it will add the new column data as rows at the end which will create null values. So, auto creating table will create **new table with date name for every column** and we can combine them into a result table with the following script referred from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17726330/18836744) by **David Söderlund**.

```
WITH rankedt1 AS
(
  SELECT Id
  ,row_number() OVER (order by Id) AS rn1
  FROM [dbo].[2022-06-28T11:55:23.1440498Ztable]
  )
,rankedt2 AS 
(
  SELECT Sname
  ,row_number() OVER (order by Sname) AS rn2
  FROM [dbo].[2022-06-28T11:55:35.8017288Ztable]
  )

SELECT
Id,Sname
FROM rankedt1
FULL OUTER JOIN rankedt2
  ON rn1=rn2
```

- You will get the result table like this in the SQL database.
  [image]