# Merge records in mysql

Tags: mysql, merge

I need to merge 2 records into one.

Mine table:

```
 ╔═════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╗
 ║ id* ║ name  ║price║ rank  ║
 ╠═════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╣
 ║  0  ║   A   ║ 12  ║  CAP  ║
 ║  1  ║   B   ║ 32  ║  BAC  ║
 ║  2  ║   B   ║ 13  ║  BAC  ║
 ╚═════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

and after merge (same table NOT SELECT)

```
 ╔═════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╗
 ║ id* ║ name  ║price║ rank  ║
 ╠═════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╣
 ║  0  ║   A   ║ 12  ║  CAP  ║
 ║  1  ║   B   ║ 45  ║  BAC  ║
 ╚═════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

looking for records that name, and rank is the same like one another and SUM price.

Merge database, and REMOVE second duplicated record.

I need to make it using Join statement or is there any faster method to do this?

Comment: hint : `sum() and group by`

Comment: Why is id '1' and not '2'?

Comment: Merge 2 to 1 co id stay at 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,   
SUM (price), rank
FROM tablename   
GROUP BY name, rank;
```

This query provides you the information needed. For more info check: 
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php

Comment: see requirement again, you lack rank column

Comment: What about grouping up other values like date and string? Im getting null or 0 values instead of grouped one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(id),name,sum(price) as price,rank,   
SUM (price)   
FROM tablename   
GROUP BY name, rank;
```

Comment: Select is quite easy, but how can i remove those duplicated records?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select name,
           SUM(price),
          @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    from your_table
    cross join (select @rownum := 0) r
    group by name
```

Counter for rank came from this post : [select increment counter in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566695/select-increment-counter-in-mysql)

Edit :
I tried it using SQL fiddle
Schema :

```
CREATE TABLE name_table
(
id int,
name varchar(5),
price decimal(10),
rank int
);

insert into name_table values(0, 'A', 12, 1);
insert into name_table values(1, 'B', 32, 2);
insert into name_table values(2, 'B', 13, 2);
```

Query :

```
select    id,
          name,
          SUM(price),
          @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    from name_table
    cross join (select @rownum := 0) r
    group by name
```

Result :

```
id  name price rank
0   A     12    1
1   B     45    2
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I remove that second record? I don't wanted to select them but make first table looks like second

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

I think below is a way by which you can achieve your output

```
SELECT name, SUM (price), rank FROM `yourtablename` GROUP BY name, rank;
```

Comment: Select is quite easy, but how can i remove those duplicated records?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be what you're after...

```
SELECT MIN(id) id 
     , name
     , SUM(price) price 
     , rank 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY name
     , rank;
```

Comment: Therw will be no changes because rank is other in all tables

Comment: 0/A/12/1
9/B/35/3
That 9 id may be other, I don' care. I need to remove that second duplicated record from database

Comment: Edited question. I need edit database, not select value

Comment: That is two operations: 1 Update and 1 Delete - or you can create a new table from the query result.

Comment: I can't, There is to much data to do this