# mysql: how to save ORDER BY after LEFT JOIN without reorder?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, sql-order-by

I've two table:

1) `profiles`

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | WILLIAM |
|  2 | JOHN    |
|  3 | ROBERT  |
|  4 | MICHAEL |
|  5 | JAMES   |
|  6 | DAVID   |
|  7 | RICHARD |
|  8 | CHARLES |
|  9 | JOSEPH  |
| 10 | THOMAS  |
+----+---------+
```

2) `request_for_friendship`

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | from_id | to_id |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |       1 |     2 |
|  2 |       1 |     3 |
|  3 |       1 |     8 |
|  5 |       4 |     1 |
|  6 |       9 |     1 |
+----+---------+-------+
```

I need to get all `profiles` with some sorting and join it with `request_for_friendship`

For example, get all users with some sorting:

```
mysql>     SELECT *
    ->     FROM  profiles
    ->     ORDER BY name ASC;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  8 | CHARLES |
|  6 | DAVID   |
|  5 | JAMES   |
|  2 | JOHN    |
|  9 | JOSEPH  |
|  4 | MICHAEL |
|  7 | RICHARD |
|  3 | ROBERT  |
| 10 | THOMAS  |
|  1 | WILLIAM | <-- WILLIAM IS LAST!
+----+---------+
```

Everything looks good, sorting is present. After that I join with `request_for_friendship` and my sotring will breaks:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT *
    ->     FROM  profiles
    ->     ORDER BY name ASC
    -> ) as users
    ->     LEFT JOIN request_for_friendship
    ->     AS request_for_friendship_copy
    ->     ON
    ->     (
    ->         request_for_friendship_copy.from_id = 1
    ->         AND
    ->         request_for_friendship_copy.to_id = users.id
    ->     )
    ->     OR
    ->     (
    ->         request_for_friendship_copy.from_id = users.id
    ->         AND
    ->         request_for_friendship_copy.to_id = 1
    ->     );
+----+---------+------+---------+-------+
| id | name    | id   | from_id | to_id |
+----+---------+------+---------+-------+
|  2 | JOHN    |    1 |       1 |     2 |
|  3 | ROBERT  |    2 |       1 |     3 |
|  8 | CHARLES |    3 |       1 |     8 |
|  4 | MICHAEL |    5 |       4 |     1 |
|  9 | JOSEPH  |    6 |       9 |     1 |
|  1 | WILLIAM | NULL |    NULL |  NULL | <-- WILLIAM IN THE MIDDLE!
|  5 | JAMES   | NULL |    NULL |  NULL |
|  6 | DAVID   | NULL |    NULL |  NULL |
|  7 | RICHARD | NULL |    NULL |  NULL |
| 10 | THOMAS  | NULL |    NULL |  NULL |
+----+---------+------+---------+-------+
```

How to `JOIN LEFT` with **original sorting** saving?

**I can't sort result after** `JOIN LEFT` besause when I do `ORDER BY` before `JOIN` it takes ~0.02s **in my db** (~1 000 000 users) but when I do `ORDER BY` after `JOIN` it takes ~3.2s, it's very big time :(

[**Demo: rextester.com/DLLM29415**](http://rextester.com/DLLM29415)

[**Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/167792/1**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/167792/1)

**In sqlfiddle order is saved! But how? MySQL 5.6 saved order?**

Comment: you should do after join all table only

Comment: @knowledge.... it totally destroy perfomance

Comment: It has to be at the end of the statement. All other Order By's are ignored.

Comment: Perhaps you need to include Name in an index.

Comment: If you put the `order by` in it's proper place (at the end), you get the correct result. If that causes unacceptable query execution time, that is a new question. You can't say "I can't do it the right way, because than the query takes too long".

Comment: if you remove it completly does the result changes? does it have an effect if it's there?

Comment: @Magnus Very strange situation! In sqlfiddle order is saved! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/167792/1 But How? MySQL 5.6 save original order?

Comment: but why all this query what is wrong with just this: `SELECT * FROM
profiles
    LEFT JOIN request_for_friendship
    AS request_for_friendship_copy
    ON
    (
        request_for_friendship_copy.from_id = 1
        AND
        request_for_friendship_copy.to_id = profiles.id
    )
  OR
    (
        request_for_friendship_copy.from_id = profiles.id
        AND
        request_for_friendship_copy.to_id = 1
    )
order by profiles.name ` ?!!

Comment: @CherifOdoo I've already ansered! -> I can't sort result after JOIN LEFT besause when I do ORDER BY before JOIN it takes ~0.02s in my db but when I do ORDER BY after JOIN it takes ~3.2s, it's very big time :( <-

Comment: it's taking 0.02 because it's not doing the order by at all i removed the order by and it gives the same result.

Comment: @CherifOdoo Really? test db with 10 000 users: http://s1.micp.ru/cE1aB.png, with 1 000 000 takes ~4 sec with order and ~0.02 sec without order!

Comment: @MixerOID if you remove the order by from the subquery nothing will change the result it's like is beeing ignored and i'm not judging you i'm just trying to figure it out too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142906/discussion-between-mixeroid-and-cherif-odoo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Explaining the loss of `ORDER BY`)

The SQL standard essentially says that a subquery is an unordered set of rows.  This implies that the Optimizer is free to ignore the `ORDER BY` in the 'derived' table: `FROM ( SELECT ... ORDER BY )`.  In "recent" versions of MySQL and MariaDB, such `ORDER BYs` are being dropped.  There are other cases where `ORDER BY` is ignored.

In *some* situations (not sure about this one), adding a `LIMIT 99999999` (big number) after the `ORDER BY` tricks the Optimizer into doing the `ORDER BY`.  However, it is still free to ignore the "order" later.

A general rule for MySQL:  Avoid subqueries.  (There are cases where subqueries are faster, but not yours.)

A strong rule:  You *must* have an `ORDER BY` on the outermost if you want the results to be sorted.

If you had added `LIMIT 3` to the derived table in your first query, you would get only CHARLES, DAVID, JAMES, *but not necessarily in that order*.  That is, you would need two `ORDER BYs` - one in the derived table, one at the very end.

Comment: Dude you are cool! The query began to work twice as fast! Your answer completely closes my question :) http://s2.micp.ru/VtWxY.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.name as `from_name`,
    b.name as `to_name`,
    c.from_id,
    c.to_id
FROM profiles a
LEFT JOIN request_for_friendship c
ON a.id = c.from_id
LEFT JOIN profiles b
ON c.to_id = b.id
GROUP BY a.name,b.name
ORDER BY a.name,b.name;
```

Or, if you want one row per "from" name:

```
SELECT
    a.name as `from_name`,
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(b.name),'-none-') as `to_name`,
    IFNULL(c.from_id,'-none-') as `from_id`,
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(c.to_id),'-none-') as `to_id`
FROM profiles a
LEFT JOIN request_for_friendship c
ON a.id = c.from_id
LEFT JOIN profiles b
ON c.to_id = b.id
GROUP BY a.name
ORDER BY a.name,b.name
```

Comment: This is a completely different result

Comment: I've updated my answer, and added a 2nd version. The first version will return one row for each combination of from / to name, plus those without requests. The 2nd returns one row per user, with a comma separated list of requests.

Comment: In full version of my sql I've beg difficult ordering like this: `ORDER BY users.city_id <> ?, users.country_id <> ?, nearest_age, RAND()` with `SELECT users.*, ABS(users.age - ?) AS nearest_age`. Main question of my topic is: `How to JOIN LEFT with original sorting saving?` and `In sqlfiddle order is saved! But how? MySQL 5.6 saved order?`

Comment: So add your order by to the query. BTW, having booleans in the order by isn't the best way -- use the IF function and return 1 or 0 instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM profiles p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN request_for_friendship r 
    ON (r.from_id = p.id AND r.to_id = 1) 
    OR (r.from_id = 1 AND r.to_id = p.id)  
 ORDER 
    BY name;
+----+---------+------+---------+-------+
| id | name    | id   | from_id | to_id |
+----+---------+------+---------+-------+
|  8 | CHARLES |    3 |       1 |     8 |
|  6 | DAVID   | NULL |    NULL |  NULL |
|  5 | JAMES   | NULL |    NULL |  NULL |
|  2 | JOHN    |    1 |       1 |     2 |
|  9 | JOSEPH  |    6 |       9 |     1 |
|  4 | MICHAEL |    5 |       4 |     1 |
|  7 | RICHARD | NULL |    NULL |  NULL |
|  3 | ROBERT  |    2 |       1 |     3 |
| 10 | THOMAS  | NULL |    NULL |  NULL |
|  1 | WILLIAM | NULL |    NULL |  NULL |
+----+---------+------+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: This query is markedly different from the one you provided above. Further, questions about performance always require, as a minimum, CREATE table statements for all relevant tables AND the results of the EXPLAIN, and finally, I'm really not a fan of your tone, so I'm bowing out of this one.

Comment: Nope. I don't do pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a couple of years old, but I didn't find this possible solution already offered. This is the solution that worked best for me to keep the subquery results in the correct order.

Consider adding a "row_number" to your subquery.  Then use ORDER BY on row_number.

This explains how to add the row_number:
[select increment counter in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566695/select-increment-counter-in-mysql)

In my case, I have an unknown number of possible rows in a hierarchical recursive query that I need to keep the order results of the subquery to remain the same in the outer query.

This is my query:

```
SELECT l.row_number, l.userid, l.child, p.id, p.username
FROM (

    SELECT  @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row_number, u.parent AS userid, _id  AS child 
                FROM (
                    SELECT  @r AS _id, (SELECT  @r := parent FROM new_clean WHERE userid = _id) AS parent
                                FROM (SELECT @r := ?) AS vars, new_clean h
                                WHERE   @r <> 0 
                    ) u
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
                WHERE u.parent <> 0                     
    ) l 

        LEFT JOIN profile p ON p.userid = l.userid
        ORDER BY row_number
```

Comment: Reading & writing the same variable in the same select statement is undefined behaviour in MySQL.

Comment: @philipxy you may be right. And I am not an expert by any means. I have reviewed much on this topic here on stackoverflow for insight.  I do think for those searching, they may also find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query/33737203#33737203