# How to easily get row number when using LIMIT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a database table with quite a few rows which I want to display to an user. It would make sense to LIMIT the output, and make pages of rows. In MySQL I would do this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY myValue LIMIT 120,10
```

which will show 10 rows starting from row 120. So MySQL must use, internally, some kind of order, and has numbered the rows accordingly. I would like to display the row number with each row. How do I get access to these numbers, using only MySQL? To be clear, I am looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *,<LIMIT_ROWNO> FROM myTable ORDER BY myValue LIMIT 120,10
```

I looked online and in the manual, but I cannot find it. I would prefer something simple, without using variables, or functions. Isn't there a predefined expression for this?

I can solve this problem easily in PHP, but it would be more logical to get the row numbers from MySQL.

Comment: There is no default order. The result is random or a better term is unrelyable.

Comment: You can try using variable..

Comment: @juergen d: In my example I haven't specified an `ORDER BY`, because it is not needed. Even if the order is random the question remains valid.

Comment: *So MySQL must use some sorting and has numbered the rows* - no!

Comment: @juergen d: Yes, otherwise the `LIMIT` could not work. I'll edit the word 'sorting' which might be confusing.

Comment: it just gets 130 rows and throws away the first 120

Comment: But you can add a sequence number for yourself if you like

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13566713/575376

Comment: @juergen d: Using variables, in this way, in expressions won't give me the `LIMIT` row number.

Comment: One thing should be clear: If you do not specify an order then the result of offset is not reliable and you don't get the correct results. You NEED an `order by`.

Comment: @juergen d: I'll add an `ORDER BY` to make it more explicit.

Comment: Now you have a garanteed order. And the answer is that you cannot access what MySQL is doing internally. You need a variable and do this for yourself

Comment: set @rownum=0;SELECT *,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as rn FROM myTable  ORDER BY myValue LIMIT 120,10;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it without using variables, e.g.:

```
SELECT m.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as `num`
FROM myTable m, (SELECT @rownum := 120) a 
ORDER BY myValue LIMIT 120,10;
```

Comment: Yes, I can see how this would work. Hiding away the initialization of `rownum` in the same query is a 'nice' touch. In the end, I choose to implement it in PHP. I've already got a complicated query, and this makes it even uglier. Anyway, you confirmed my suspicion that I cannot get the row number more directly from MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
set @rownum=120;
SELECT *,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as rn FROM myTable ORDER BY myValue LIMIT 120,10;
```

Answer (score 1):

as of final of 2021, why not:

```
SELECT 
t1.*, 
COUNT(t1.*) OVER (PARTITION BY RowCounter) as TotalRecords
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, 1 as RowCounter 
    FROM MyTable
) t1 
LIMIT 120,10
```

using a subquery with a column marking every row with the same value, will give us the possibility to count all of the same values of the the resulted column with [PARTITION BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) window function's group

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: It seems the [Window Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions-overview/) were only introduced in MariaDB 10.2. We are using MariaDB 5.5. I cannot test your answer, unless I set up a complete test-environment for the latest version. I don't have time for that. I do however understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I found a [database fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mKTd9StqeZVxm4QZLBjwau/0) to run your query. I don't think it does what I asked for in my question.

Comment: Ah sorry, I've answered accordingly with the title lol :)))