# How do I calculate which page a result occurs on with MySQL and PHP?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a link to a specific forum post. To do this, I need to calculate which page within the thread the post is on since I am using pagination. How can I calculate which page a message will be on based on the number of results per page?

I use the following query to find the total number of messages in the thread:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(message_id) AS total_messages, thread_id
FROM forum_messages
WHERE thread_id = 1
```

Comment: in which order will they come? You didn't specify that, so you cannot know.

Comment: You're using pagination, but you have no clue as to how that works? Weird.

Comment: (A) What does this have to do with linking to a specific record?  (B) For what you're asking, it's impossible to know.  All this code does is tell you how many matching records you have.  It doesn't tell you anything *about* those records, what order they're in, etc.

Comment: see this answer for how to get the position (an increment number) of a row in a select: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566695/select-increment-counter-in-mysql Might be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You need to number the rows based on the order used to paginate them, and then just calculate the page based on the page size:

```
-- supposing a page size of 10 and pagination order by message_id
select message_id, ceiling(message_number/10) as page
from (
  select message_id, @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS message_number
  from forum_messages, (select @row_number:=0) AS row_number
  order by message_id
) as numbered_messages
where message_id=<the id of the message>
```

These blog post explain the trick used for simulating `ROW_NUMBER()` in MySQL:

[MySQL – Generating Row Number for Each Row Using Variable](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/08/mysql-generating-row-number-for-each-row-using-variable/)

Answer (score 0):

In general, `page number` doesn't depend on the number of records, but the number of records per page:

```
page_no = (message_position DIV records_per_page) + 1
```

You can translate this to any meaningful only if the `message_position` is consecutive in a `thread_id`. If not, you can't calculate page_no.