# MySQL SELECT INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, distinct, increment

Reading this post: [MySQL SELECT increment counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566695/mysql-select-increment-counter)
I tried the solution by juergen d and was successful, except when I attempted to use DISTINCT on the selected column, it returns the primary key values for each row rather than an indexed value.
The successful query:

```
SELECT city,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER() 
FROM addresses 
WHERE city IS NOT NULL AND city <> '' 
ORDER BY city;
```

City can be the same for multiple rows, so the desire is to return only distinct values with the ordered numerical column.

Comment: Sample data might help the question so other users can build and test in sqlfiddle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the distinct values, then use `ROW_NUMBER()` in the main query.

```
SELECT city, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT city
    FROM addresses
    WHERE city IS NOT NULL AND city <> ''
) AS x
ORDER BY city
```